# How to assign value to text object in crystal reports from powerbuilder at runtime

Tags: crystal-reports, report, powerbuilder

Pls help me to assign value to text object in crystal report from powerbuilder script at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

You may try something like this:

`g_ole_crx_report.ReportDefinition.ReportObjects["Text1" ].text = "aaaaaaaaaaaa"`